# Getting API error with square-commerce-v1 URL scheme

Tags: square-connect

I'm trying to initiate a Square Register payment from a web app. The web app will only run on iPads that are within my control.

The HTML I'm using to call it takes this form:

```
<a href="square-commerce-v1://payment/create?data=%7B%0A%22amount_money%22%3A%20%7B%0A%22amount%22%3A%20500%2C%20%0A%22currency_code%22%3A%20%22USD%22%20%0A%7D%2C%0A%22callback_url%22%3A%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fmycallbackurl.org%22%2C%0A%22client_id%22%3A%20%22{{my_app_id}}%22%2C%0A%22merchant_id%22%3A%20%22{{my_merchant_ID}}%22%2C%0A%22supported_tender_types%22%3A%20%5B%0A%22CREDIT_CARD%22%2C%0A%22CASH%22%0A%5D%0A%7D">Open Square Register</a>
```

Where the `data` parameter is, I believe, a properly URL-encoded form of this:

```
{
  "amount_money": {
    "amount": 500, 
    "currency_code": "USD" 
  },
  "callback_url": "https://mycallbackurl.org",
  "client_id": "{{my_app_id}",
  "merchant_id": "{{my_merchant_id}}",
  "supported_tender_types": [
    "CREDIT_CARD",
    "CASH"
  ]
}
```

The Square Register app is giving me this error:

> **API Error**
> Sorry, we could not process the incoming request. Please try again or contact support.

What am I doing wrong? Is this possible to do from a web app, as I'm trying to?

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur if your application is not authorized to use the Square Commerce API. From the [documentation](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api#commerce-api-overview):

> The Commerce API is currently available only to approved partners. If you're interested in using the Commerce API to integrate your iOS app with Square Register, please contact partners@squareup.com.

Comment: Note that as of 2015, this is no longer true. Anyone can create a square account and use the APIs.

Answer (score 0):

In their API docs it says that supported tender types should be nested under options:

```
{
  "options": {
    "supported_tender_types": [
      "CREDIT_CARD"
    ]
  }
}
```